# How to test my iOS app for IP v6 compatibility?

Tags: ios, testing, ipv6

I found out today that from 1st of June Apple will require iOS apps to use only IP v.6.

I don't have any new publication soon but I need to test our company apps for compatibility. How to force my iOS app to use IP v.6 only?

EDIT: We have SOAP service which is used by the app. We have IP v.6 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple provided document on how to test IPv6 Support [Test for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility Regularly](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16).

This include a setup where your development machine is used a IPv6 net router.